# add delay for a task until particular file is moved from bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I have to check for a file which is generated from DAG `(eg: sample.txt)` is moved from bucket(in my case the file I have generated will be moved away from the bucket when picked up by other system, and then there won't be this output file in the bucket. It might take few minutes for the file to be removed from bucket)

How to add a task in the same DAG where it waits/retires till the file is moved away from the bucket and when the sample.txt file is moved away then proceed with the next task.

Is there any operator which satisfies the above criteria? please throw some light on how to proceed

Comment: there is a class of `Operators` called `Sensors`, you might wanna use `S3Sensor`, it actually checks if a file exists in particular location in s3 or not. you requirement is actually opposite of what it does but you should be able to use it to achieve the same.

Comment: yes, I came across this operator and I want to perform something opposite of what sensor does  as you said, I want to understand how to use the `sensor` operator if it can be tweaked to satisfy the above requirement. How to add the condition to wait for 'sample.txt' file  to moved from bucket and then proceed for next task. @AnandVidvat

Comment: you can extend the`S3KeySensor` and override the `execute` method to achieve your requirement.  please refer to see the implementation of execute method:  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.4/_modules/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.html#BaseSensorOperator.execute

Comment: since your Cloud Provider is GCP, you might have to tweek the implementation of poke function as well, I am not aware if file sensor for gcp is available or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom sensor based on the current [GCSObjectExistenceSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs.py#L30)

The modification is simple:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs import GCSObjectExistenceSensor
class GCSObjectNotExistenceSensor(GCSObjectExistenceSensor):

    def poke(self, context: dict) -> bool:
        self.log.info('Sensor checks if : %s, %s does not exist', self.bucket, self.object)
        hook = GCSHook(
            gcp_conn_id=self.google_cloud_conn_id,
            delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
            impersonation_chain=self.impersonation_chain,
        )
        return not hook.exists(self.bucket, self.object)
```

Then use the sensor `GCSObjectNotExistenceSensor` in your code like:

```
gcs_object_does_not_exists = GCSObjectNotExistenceSensor(
    bucket=BUCKET_1,
    object=PATH_TO__FILE,
    mode='poke',
    task_id="gcs_object_does_not_exists_task",
)
```

The sensor will not let the pipeline to continue until the object `PATH_TO__FILE` is removed.

Comment: @RvR all sensors inherit from `BaseSensorOperator` the `poke_interval` has default value. you can overwrite this in the sensor.

Comment: +Elad do add your comment above to the solution as an extended requirement of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use airflow PythonOperator to achieve the task. Make the Python callable continuously poke GCS and check if the file is removed. Return from Python function when the file from GCS is removed.

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from google.cloud import storage
import google.auth

def check_file_in_gcs():
    credentials, project = google.auth.default()
    storage_client = storage.Client('your_Project_id', credentials=credentials)
    name = 'sample.txt'   
    bucket_name = 'Your_Bucket_name'
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    while True:
        stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name=name).exists(storage_client)
        if not stats:
           print("Returning as file is removed!!!!")
           return

check_gcs_file_removal = PythonOperator(
            task_id='check_gcs_file_removal',
            python_callable= check_file_in_gcs,
            #op_kwargs={'params': xyz},
            #Pass bucket name and other details if needed by commentating above 
            dag=dag
        )
```

you might need to install Python packages for the google cloud libraries to work. Please install one from below. (Not sure which one to install exactly.Taken from my virtualenv)

```
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.0
google-auth==1.12.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.27.0
```

Comment: This works well if your task only needs to run for small time frame say, couple of mintues but if the task to be run for couple of hours then the worker node will be very much occupied so this is not a recommended approach